# Change the Python3 default version in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, python, python3

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS . I have `python3` installed. There are  two versions installed, `python 3.4.3` and `python 3.6` . Whenever I use `python3` command, it takes `python 3.4.3` by default. I want to use `python 3.6` with `python3`.

`python3 --version` shows `version 3.4.3`

I am installing `ansible` which supports `version > 3.5` . So, whenever, I type ansible in the terminal, it throws error because of `python 3.4`

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python3
```

Comment: What is the command used to execute python 3.6 ?

Comment: command is :- python3.6

Comment: What does your `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` say?

Comment: update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python3

Comment: See my comment in the below answer on how to use ansible with a specific version of python3. You could also consider removing python 3.4.

Comment: @Mikael Different Python versions are not alternatives on Ubuntu. The OS relies on a specific version (or versions) being installed.

Comment: Just run: `sudo apt install python-is-python3`

Comment: Best / safest to add alias `python3="python3.6"` to ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 427):

From the comment:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

Will show you an error:

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python3
```

You need to update your `update-alternatives` , then you will be able to set your default python version.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.4 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6 2
```

Then run :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

Set python3.6 as default.

Or use the following command to set python3.6 as default:

```
sudo update-alternatives  --set python /usr/bin/python3.6
```

Comment: This answer will probably break `apt`. After selecting a different version of python try to run `sudo apt update`. If it gives you an error like `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'` you want to go to `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` and create the symlink: `ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{34m,36m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

Comment: It gives me an error: `$ sudo update-alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3.6
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python` Any suggestions?

Comment: @GAD3R Thanks. I've managed to create a symlink manually to point to the Python 3.6. Also, I don't have 3.7 installed.

Comment: Making `python3` point to `python3.8` with this method broke `gnome-terminal` for me.

Comment: @Boris Did you find a way to point to python3.8 succesfully?

Comment: @Johny I just added `alias python="python3.8"` to `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @Boris Yes, I ended up doing the same.

Comment: Don't do this. It will break `apt` like @Giacomo mentioned along with other OS components [like `do-release-upgrade`](https://askubuntu.com/q/1104052/301745). Simply use an alias instead.

Comment: @Boris I personally do not like to clutter my .bash_profile with aliases. And by the way, what happens when you use another shell? ;)

Comment: I had an error `update-alternatives: error: alternative link /usr/bin/python is already managed by python`. So I could not use the `update-alternatives` method. The only solution is to change the symlink as in @IRSHAD answer below.

Comment: Works fine in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS without breaking APT.

Note to those confused: if you are getting the `error: no alternatives for python` message, then you need to run the `--install` commands following first (replacing the python versions you want to use as appropriate, and the numbers at the end are just for order) then you run the `--config` command again and you will be asked which version you want to use by default.

Comment: this helped to me `sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
` to repair no module named `apt-get`.

Comment: In Ubuntu 22, this gives: `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python`

Comment: @Cerin Please ask a new detailed question. Which python version you have installed?

Answer (score 74):

You can achieve this by applying below simple steps -

1. Check python version on terminal: `python --version`
2. Execute this command to switch to python 3.6:

   ```bash
   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 1
   ```
3. Check python version: `python --version`
4. Done.

Comment: Works fine on Ubuntu 18.04. so simple than other solutions. thanks a lot

Comment: @Sam-T your comment didn't work for me. I am on Debian 10 & this worked for me `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.7 1; python --version`

Comment: This command doesn't change the behavior for dependencies such as pip. After executing this, pip was still using the older version of python.

Answer (score 43):

if you have multiple version of python in your system. You just need to update the symbolic link of python inside `/usr/bin/`

```
root@irshad:/usr/bin# ls -lrth python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Apr 16  2018 python -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.6M Nov 12  2018 python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.4M May  7 14:58 python3.6
```

In above example if you see the output of `python --version` you will get **python2.7**

Now update the python symlink using below command-

```
root@irshad:/usr/bin# unlink python
root@irshad:/usr/bin# ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 python
root@irshad:/usr/bin# python --version
Python 3.6.8
```

Comment: I agree this answer is the best. However, I would add that some people's newly installed python won't be located in `/usr/bin/pythonX.X`. Instead figure out the location with `which pythonX.X` and substitute in.

Comment: I couldn't find the newly installed python3.9 in /user/bin/, any suggestion please? I am on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Note that if you don't have root permission, then u may need execute the above commands with `sudo`.

Comment: I needed this variation: 
sudo unlink /usr/bin/python3,
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3,
python3 --version

Answer (score 27):

Using these commands can help you:

1. check the version of python:
   `ls /usr/bin/python*`
2. alias:
   `alias python='/usr/bin/pythonxx'` (add this to `. ~/.bashrc`)
3. re-login or source `. ~/.bashrc`
4. check the python version again:
   `python --version`

Comment: thanks but after restarting the computer the main python would be still the ex python 2.7

Comment: You should add the script to modify the default in ~/.bashrc. Then you will make it work forever.

Comment: like this: export python=/home/xxx (your py3 directory)

Answer (score 14):

First check that you have a python3.6 folder?

`ls /usr/bin/python3.6`

If you have "python3.6" folder, you are good to go. Now update-alternatives

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1
```

then update new config for python3

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

Finally, check default python3 version:

```
python3 --version
```

Comment: nit: you don't have folders under bin, you have executables.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: This broke `sudo apt-get update` for me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'`

Answer (score 6):

Create symlink for /usr/bin/python3.
In my LinuxMint:

```
# ls -lh /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 ноя 24  2017 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 сен  6  2017 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.5

# mv /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python.bak
# cp /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
# python --version
Python 3.5.2
```

Comment: This broke apt installer.

Answer (score 5):

An easy answer would be to add an alias for python3.6.

Just add this line in the file ~/.bashrc : `alias python3="python3.6"`, then close your terminal and open a new one. Now when you type `python3 xxx` it gets translated to `python3.6 xxx`.

This solution fixes your problem without needing to tweak your system too heavily.

**EDIT :**

As [Mikael Kjær](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/171862/mikael-kj%C3%A6r) pointed out, this is a misconfiguration of ansible with your system.

As seen [here :](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/python_3_support.html)

> Set the `ansible_python_interpreter` configuration option to
>   /usr/bin/python3. The ansible_python_interpreter configuration option
>   is usually set per-host as an inventory variable associated with a
>   host or group of hosts:
>
> ```
>   # Example inventory that makes an alias for localhost that uses python3
>   [py3-hosts]
>   localhost-py3 ansible_host=localhost ansible_connection=local
>
>   [py3-hosts:vars]
>   ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
> ```

As seen [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#configuration-file) about the config file :

> Changes can be made and used in a configuration file which will be processed in the following order:
>
> ```
> * ANSIBLE_CONFIG (an environment variable)
> * ansible.cfg (in the current directory)
> * .ansible.cfg (in the home directory)
> * /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
> ```

Comment: Actually, I am installing ansible , which supports only > python 3.5

Comment: You can set the `ansible_python_interpreter` variable to use your python3.6. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/python_3_support.html

Comment: @MikaelKjær I just added your comment to my answer

Answer (score 4):

update-alternatives is to change system symlinks to user-defined/admin-defined symlinks.
If you have multiple versions of python3 installed in your system and want to control which python3 version to invoke when python3 is called. Do the following

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.4 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.5 2
```

Run below command if you want to change priority in the future.

```
update-alternatives --config python3
```

Explanation:-

```
sudo update-alternatives --install <symlink_origin> <name_of_config> <symlink_destination> <priority>
```

You can go on change name_of_config to python4, but then you have to invoke update-alternatives --config with python4 to reconfigure.

Using this approach you are able to control system python version and python3 version separately.

Comment: This is one of only 2 answers that updates python3 without updating the python version and this one seems to have been first.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410579/change-the-python3-default-version-in-ubuntu#comment1255620_410579) by [Slion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/489333/slion),`sudo apt install python-is-python3` will do this for you in a reasonable way, currently IIUC by added an appropriate symlink.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the simbolic link by `ln -sf python3.6 python3` inside `/usr/bin`. With this when you call `python3` it will execute `python3.6`