# Broken python during Debian 8->9 upgrade

Tags: debian, apt, kde, python3, dist-upgrade

So I was in the process of upgrading a Debian 8 to 9 following [those instructions](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-upgrade-debian-8-jessie-to-debian-9-stretch). Something went wrong, python broke and now I haven't been able to fix it after hours on it. Some samples:

```
# apt-get install --fix-broken       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
coinor-libcoinmp1v5 kde-style-oxygen kde-style-oxygen-qt4 libboost-date-time1.62.0 libboost-filesystem1.62.0 libboost-iostreams1.62.0
...
libkf5mailcommon5 libkf5mailimporter5 libkf5messagecomposer5 libkf5messagelist5 libkf5sendlater5 libkf5templateparser5 libkjsembed4 libkntlm4
libokularcore7 liborcus-0.11-0 libpagemaker-0.0-0 libspeechd2 libwps-0.4-4
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
accountsservice akonadi-backend-mysql akonadi-server akregator apper appstream appstream-index apt apt-utils ark baloo-kf5 bluedevil bluez
...
python-mpi4py python-scipy python3 python3-apt python3-cffi-backend python3-chardet python3-crypto python3-cryptography python3-dbus
python3-debian python3-decorator python3-dev python3-gi python3-idna python3-joblib python3-keyring python3-keyrings.alt python3-minimal
python3-nose python3-numpy python3-pkg-resources python3-py python3-pyasn1 python3-pycurl python3-pyqt4 python3-pyqt5 python3-pytest
python3-secretstorage python3-setuptools python3-simplejson python3-sip python3-six python3-software-properties python3-wheel python3-xdg
python3.5 python3.5-dev qapt-batch qdbus qdbus-qt5 qml-module-org-kde-activities qml-module-org-kde-bluezqt qml-module-org-kde-draganddrop
...
task-ssh-server tasksel tasksel-data uno-libs3 ure user-manager vlc vlc-bin vlc-data vlc-l10n vlc-nox vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-notify
vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-samba vlc-plugin-video-output
Suggested packages:
gnome-control-center akonadi-backend-postgresql akonadi-backend-sqlite limba apt-doc powermgmt-base pulseaudio-module-bluetooth bluez-alsa
...
vlc-plugin-skins2 vlc-plugin-video-splitter vlc-plugin-visualization
The following packages will be REMOVED:
aptitude coinor-libcoinmp1 coinor-libcoinutils3 coinor-libosi1 gparted juk k3b k3b-i18n kaccessible katepart kde-baseapps kde-baseapps-bin
...
task-kde-desktop vlc-plugin-pulse
The following NEW packages will be installed:
accountsservice appstream baloo-kf5 bluedevil bluez bluez-obexd breeze breeze-cursor-theme breeze-icon-theme catdoc coinor-libcoinmp1v5
...
python3-cffi-backend python3-crypto python3-cryptography python3-idna python3-keyring python3-keyrings.alt python3-py python3-pyasn1
python3-pycurl python3-pytest python3-secretstorage python3-xdg python3.5 python3.5-dev qdbus-qt5 qml-module-org-kde-activities
...
python3-debian python3-decorator python3-dev python3-gi python3-joblib python3-minimal python3-nose python3-numpy python3-pkg-resources
python3-pyqt4 python3-pyqt5 python3-setuptools python3-simplejson python3-sip python3-six python3-software-properties python3-wheel qapt-batch
qdbus qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qtquick-window2 qml-module-qtquick2 qt4-designer qt4-dev-tools
qt4-linguist-tools qt4-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools qtchooser qtcreator qtcreator-data qtdeclarative5-dev-tools qttools5-dev-tools
software-properties-kde sqlitebrowser systemsettings task-desktop task-english task-ssh-server tasksel tasksel-data uno-libs3 ure vlc vlc-data
vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-samba
211 upgraded, 514 newly installed, 165 to remove and 243 not upgraded.
25 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/488 MB of archives.
After this operation, 409 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Reading changelogs... Done
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 223763 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../software-properties-kde_0.96.20.2-1+deb9u1_all.deb ...
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 580, in <module>
    main()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 566, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 287, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 263, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 253, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 595, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 538, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 410, in _init_posix
    from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _sysconfigdata_m import *
ImportError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m'
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 580, in <module>
    main()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 566, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 287, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 263, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 253, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 595, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 538, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 410, in _init_posix
    from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _sysconfigdata_m import *
ImportError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/software-properties-kde_0.96.20.2-1+deb9u1_all.deb (--unpack):
subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 580, in <module>
    main()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 566, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 287, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 263, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 253, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 595, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 538, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 410, in _init_posix
    from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _sysconfigdata_m import *
ImportError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m'
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/software-properties-kde_0.96.20.2-1+deb9u1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Also on single packages:

```
# apt-get install --reinstall python3-minimal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
apper : Depends: packagekit (>= 0.8.6) but it is not going to be installed
python3 : Depends: python3-minimal (= 3.4.2-2) but 3.5.3-1 is to be installed
software-properties-kde : Depends: python3-software-properties (= 0.96.20.2-1+deb9u1) but 0.92.25debian1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And basically the same as above with python3 or python

```
# dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq --force-depends python3            
dpkg: python3: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
python3-pygments depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
software-properties-common depends on python3 (>= 3.2.3-3~).
python3-joblib depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
python3-debian depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
Package python3 is to be removed.
python3-ptyprocess depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
python3-traitlets depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
Package python3 is to be removed.
python3-decorator depends on python3 (>= 3.2.3-3~).
dh-python depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
debian-goodies depends on python3.
python3-pykde4 depends on python3 (<< 3.5).
python3-pykde4 depends on python3 (>= 3.4~).
python3-pykde4 depends on python3 (<< 3.5).
python3-pykde4 depends on python3 (>= 3.4~).
python3-setuptools depends on python3:any (>= 3.3).
python3-setuptools depends on python3:any (<< 3.5).
python3-setuptools depends on python3:any (>= 3.3).
python3-setuptools depends on python3:any (<< 3.5).
python3-software-properties depends on python3 (>= 3.2.3-3~).
python3-sip depends on python3 (>= 3.4~).
python3-sip depends on python3 (<< 3.5).
python3-sip depends on python3 (>= 3.4~).
python3-sip depends on python3 (<< 3.5).
unattended-upgrades depends on python3.
python3-pip depends on python3:any (>= 3.4~).
python3-chardet depends on python3.
python3-chardet depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
python3-chardet depends on python3.
python3-chardet depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
python3-pexpect depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
Package python3 is to be removed.
python3-nose depends on python3; however:
Package python3 is to be removed.
python3-nose depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
Package python3 is to be removed.
python3-nose depends on python3; however:
Package python3 is to be removed.
python3-nose depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
Package python3 is to be removed.
python3-ipython-genutils depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
python3-uno depends on python3 (>= 3.4~).
python3-uno depends on python3 (<< 3.5).
python3-uno depends on python3 (>= 3.4~).
python3-uno depends on python3 (<< 3.5).
python3-pyqt4 depends on python3 (>= 3.4~).
python3-pyqt4 depends on python3 (<< 3.5).
python3-pyqt4 depends on python3 (>= 3.4~).
python3-pyqt4 depends on python3 (<< 3.5).
python3-wcwidth depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
lsb-release depends on python3:any (>= 3.4~).
python3-gi depends on python3 (>= 3.4~).
python3-gi depends on python3 (<< 3.5).
python3-gi depends on python3 (>= 3.4~).
python3-gi depends on python3 (<< 3.5).
python3-pkg-resources depends on python3:any (>= 3.3).
python3-pkg-resources depends on python3:any (<< 3.5).
python3-pkg-resources depends on python3:any (>= 3.3).
python3-pkg-resources depends on python3:any (<< 3.5).
python3-wheel depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
python3-wheel depends on python3.
python3-wheel depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
python3-wheel depends on python3.
gdebi-core depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
software-properties-kde depends on python3 (>= 3.2.3-3~).
python3-dev depends on python3 (= 3.4.2-2).
python3-six depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
python3-simplejson depends on python3 (>= 3.4~).
python3-simplejson depends on python3 (<< 3.5).
python3-simplejson depends on python3 (>= 3.4~).
python3-simplejson depends on python3 (<< 3.5).
python3-pyqt5 depends on python3 (>= 3.4~).
python3-pyqt5 depends on python3 (<< 3.5).
python3-pyqt5 depends on python3 (>= 3.4~).
python3-pyqt5 depends on python3 (<< 3.5).
python3-numpy depends on python3 (>= 3.4~).
python3-numpy depends on python3 (<< 3.5).
python3-numpy depends on python3 (>= 3.4~).
python3-numpy depends on python3 (<< 3.5).
python3-ipython depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
Package python3 is to be removed.
ipython3 depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
Package python3 is to be removed.
python3-dbus depends on python3 (<< 3.5).
python3-dbus depends on python3 (>= 3.4~).
python3-dbus depends on python3 (<< 3.5).
python3-dbus depends on python3 (>= 3.4~).
python3-apt depends on python3 (<< 3.5).
python3-apt depends on python3 (>= 3.4~).
python3-apt depends on python3 (<< 3.5).
python3-apt depends on python3 (>= 3.4~).
python3-prompt-toolkit depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
Package python3 is to be removed.
python3-simplegeneric depends on python3 (>= 3.1.3-13~).
python3-pickleshare depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).

(Reading database ... 223763 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python3 (3.4.2-2) ...
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 580, in <module>
    main()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 566, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 287, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 263, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 253, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 595, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 538, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 410, in _init_posix
    from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _sysconfigdata_m import *
ImportError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m'
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--remove):
subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 580, in <module>
    main()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 566, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 287, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 263, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 253, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 595, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 538, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 410, in _init_posix
    from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _sysconfigdata_m import *
ImportError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m'
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
python3
```

I've tried this but an error in another missing package happens:

```
# ln -fs /usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu/_sysconfigdata_m.py /usr/lib/python3.5/
```

A lot of things are now broken:

```
# lsb_release -a
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 580, in <module>
    main()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 566, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 287, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 263, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 253, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 595, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 538, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 410, in _init_posix
    from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _sysconfigdata_m import *
ImportError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m'
```

But the upgrade is halfway through:

```
# cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 9 \n \l

# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
VERSION_CODENAME=stretch
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"


# ll $(which python)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jan 24  2017 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7*
# ll $(which python3)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11855256 Jun 13  2019 /usr/bin/python3*
```

Why does the installer insist on using a broken python3 instead of python (which is 2.7) ? And how do I fix this mess ?

Edit:

```
# apt policy python3
E: Invalid operation policy
# apt-cache policy python3
python3:
  Installed: 3.4.2-2
  Candidate: 3.5.3-1
  Version table:
     3.5.3-1 0
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch/main amd64 Packages
 *** 3.4.2-2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

# uname -a
Linux myserver2c 3.16.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.84-1 (2020-06-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What does `apt policy python3` say?

Comment: Also, for future reference, you might want to follow [the instructions provided by Debian](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html) when performing upgrades, instead of some random third party’s. (I don’t think there’s anything substantially incorrect in the instructions you followed, but as a general rule, please follow the Debian release notes.)

Comment: @A.B In the specific case of upgrading from jessie to stretch, Debian's own instructions also recommend running first upgrade and then dist-upgrade. The explanation is that running dist-upgrade directly "might remove large numbers of packages that you will want to keep."

Comment: @telcoM right. my bad ( https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#minimal-upgrade )

Comment: Have 32-bit or 64-bit OS?

Comment: I added answers to the comments at the end of the original message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem come from the security repository, it is not set correctly.

Replace the following line described in [the webpage](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-upgrade-debian-8-jessie-to-debian-9-stretch):

```
deb http://security.debian.org stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

with:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

To solve the python error switch to python2.7. See [Change the Python3 default version in Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410579/change-the-python3-default-version-in-ubuntu/410851#410851). Then create a  `/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.postinst` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/true
```

Then run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

If still doesn't work remove python3 from `/var/lib/dpkg/status` after backup then run the above commands.

Comment: I still get the `ImportError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m'` error

Comment: Short of doing a manual compilation of python3, I don't see how...

Comment: @dargaud Don't compile, reinstall it through `apt`.

Comment: `dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq --force-depends python3` fails, see above. If you have a magical incantation that works, I'd love to hear it !

Comment: @dargaud See my edit. Have you solved the Unmet dependencies problem?

Comment: python already soflinks to python2.7, isn't that enough?

Comment: `# dpkg --configure -a` `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pickleshare: python3-pickleshare depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however: Package python3 is not configured yet` and repeats

Comment: @dargaud remove  `python3-pickleshare`  then `dpkg --configure -a` then reinstall it.

Comment: Editing /var/lib/dpkg/status seems to have worked. dist-upgrade worked and I'm now rebooting. Do I need to revert it afterwards ?

Comment: @dargaud Check if `python3` work properly then revert back to it.

Comment: Yes, it works, the update replaced 3.4 with 3.5. A big thank you!

Comment: @dargaud Great! You are welcome.