# Problem in Python (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, python, pip

When I try to install this, I get this error; what is the solution?

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx:~/URLuploader-With-Hotstar$ pip3 install -r requirements.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip.locations import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/locations.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils import sysconfig
ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig' from 'distutils' (/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you're missing `python3-distutils` package, install via:

```
sudo apt install python3-distutils
```

See also:

- [Issue on github](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5356)
- [Question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63823964/importerror-cannot-import-name-sysconfig-from-distutils-usr-lib-python3-8)
- [Question on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1292972/importerror-cannot-import-name-sysconfig-from-distutils-usr-lib-python3-9).

Comment: I encountered another problem
https://jpst.it/2tZuP

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `python3.8-distutils` the suitable package to your python version (`python3.8`):

```
sudo apt install python3.8-distutils
```

Switch to python3.8 [following this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410579/change-the-python3-default-version-in-ubuntu/410851#410851).

Reinstall `pip3`:

```
sudo apt remove python3-pip
cd /tmp
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3.8 get-pip.py
pip3 install pyrogram
```

Comment: I encountered another problem https://jpst.it/2tZuP

Comment: @MohamedHayoun set your default python to 3.8, see how to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/410851/153195

Comment: now look at this:
` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pyrogram import Client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyrogram'`

Comment: @MohamedHayoun `pip3 install pyrogram`

Comment: https://justpaste.it/27qs7

Comment: @MohamedHayoun see my update please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123159/discussion-between-mohamed-hayoun-and-gad3r).