# pip install command fails

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux, python3

### Q: how do I fix this pip install issue?

I tried to install some libs with

```bash
pip3 install pinecone-client openai tiktoken langchain
```

and this happened:

```shellsession
$ pip3 install pinecone-client openai tiktoken langchain
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==20.0.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.package_finder import PackageFinder
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.collector import parse_links
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests
ImportError: cannot import name 'html5lib' from 'pip._vendor' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py)
```

I am new to python so I'm not sure of the best approach to resolve it.
Thanks.

Comment: "Ever since I tried installing python to start learning python" ... What exactly did you? Please add the actual steps you did to the question.

Comment: @muru I can't because it was a while ago, involved many steps while trying to follow a tutorial. I only added it to the question because I thought it might be related to the query that DOES have the steps shown. I'll delete the first part of the question then.

Comment: If you messed up your system version of Python somehow, and don't know exactly how, then the best option is to just reinstall.

Comment: @mumu When I said _involved many steps_, one of those steps would have been my attempts to reinstall. I think I now have python 2, 3, and 3.11. I think at this point I will just google how to uninstall everything.

Comment: Ah, I meant re-install _Ubuntu_, not re-install Python.

Comment: Yeah, at this point it's really easier to just make a new Ubuntu machine instead of trying to fix this one that you can't even describe how you broke it. In general, avoid installing via pip and use apt to install Python and Python modules, as far as feasible.

Comment: To avoid problems with Python versions and such use [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

Answer (score 0):

- Using Python3.10 (defaut)

Switch back to Pyhon3.10 the default python version for Ubuntu Jammy. [Change the Python3 default version in Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410579/change-the-python3-default-version-in-ubuntu)

- Using Python3.11

Install Python3.11 from the official repositories:

Python3.11 is available from `jammy-updates universe` repository. You should have the following line in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main universe
```

Remove the installed Python3.11 from third party repository (or compiled), then:

```
sudo apt remove python3.11
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.11
```

Check if `pip` work correctly with Python3.11:

```
python3.11 -m pip install pinecone-client openai tiktoken langchain
```

Comment: This was helpful up to a point! 1) I leaned I was on focal, not jammy 2) you fixed my sudo apt install / update which had been broken. But when I got to the last step (the pip  install) I got (qualitatively) the same errors per my Q; just the line numbers etc were different. :-/